# How can you use groovy inside Play! Framework, outside of templates?

Tags: java, groovy, playframework

[The FAQ](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/faq#aIsplayaGroovyframeworka) states

> Is play a Groovy framework?
>
> No. Even if we use Groovy as the base technology for the Play
> templating system, it’s totally transparent. Also, you can’t write
> directly any other part of the application (such as controllers,
> models or other utilities) in Groovy. If you’re looking for a Groovy
> based framework you should have a look at Grails.

While I get that it's not supported out of the box, I do believe/hope the integration is possible ... I mean, Java is Turing Complete after all :)

So, has anyone experimented in writing Groovy code, and calling that code from Play! Controllers? What's the best way to achieve that?

**Bonus points**: If the solution worked seamlessly with IntelliJ, that would be heaven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the documentation, Play is not a Groovy framework. Is is plain java and I am not aware of any initiative of using Groovy in Play.

Plus, bonus point, Play2 has completly removed Groovy even in templates to be replaced by Scala. So I think that even if a solution exists it might not be maintained in the future.

Comment: Well, we wanted to migrate to Scala at some point, but decided learning Play alone is sufficient work for now, I don't want to start learning Scala at the same time. Plus Play 2.0 isn't production yet (I heard the recent beta release was called 'alpha' in one of the threads). For now, I'll just use plain old java - thanks!

Comment: Indeed, Play2 is still in alpha and will evolve a lot during the following months with a RC version in a couple of months. Too early to use in production. I would stick with plain Play for the moment and migrate toward Play2 when it hits release. ;)

Comment: I never tried it, but here is an example: https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/play2-groovy-templates