# Play!: How to place property value in groovy expression

Tags: java, html, groovy, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have such code in my play! view

```
 <button type="submit">${edit ? 'edit' : 'init'}</button>
```

I want to replace 'edit' and 'init' with property value. like

```
&{'button.edit'}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What does Play framework that is based on Scala has to do with Groovy? Are you sure you are not talking about Grails?

Comment: Please provide a link where it states that Play! framework employs Groovy. As far as I can tell Play! uses Scala and Java, it doesn't really employ Groovy!!! Prove: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227007/how-can-you-use-groovy-inside-play-framework-outside-of-templates & also: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0/faq#aIsplayaGroovyframeworka

Comment: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/templates

Comment: My 2 cents: newer version of Play! doesn't use Groovy for templates! Therefore I would advice to switch to Scala. If you love Groovy, you might wanna look at Grails framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "property value" but here are two interpretations:

---

Use `&{''}` if `button.edit` is defined in your `conf/messages.en` file (or whatever language).

```
&{'button.edit'}
```

---

Use `${}` if `button` is an object and you are reading the `edit` field from its class.

```
${button.edit}
```